# Why does checking for a role require a cross-partition query?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

On the azure portal, I created Cosmos DB (core (SQL) API), added a `users` container (partition key `id`) and `roles` (partition key `name`) there. Installed the `CodeKoenig.AspNetCore.Identity.DocumentDb` package. Then, when I try to determine whether a role exists in the database through the role manager, I get a `DocumentClientException: Cross partition query is required but disabled. Please set x-ms-documentdb-query-enablecrosspartition to true, specify x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey, or revise your query to avoid this exception`. This is how I configured the identity service:

```
services.AddIdentity<Models.Entities.User, DocumentDbIdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddDocumentDbStores(options =>
    {
        options.Database = "forumdb";
        options.UserStoreDocumentCollection = "users";
        options.RoleStoreDocumentCollection = "roles";
    })
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Code that throws an exception:

```
var roleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<DocumentDbIdentityRole>>();
roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(roleName).Result;
```

`Models.Entities.User` inherits from `AspNetCore.Identity.DocumentDb.DocumentDbIdentityUser`. I doubt there should be a сross partition request to check if a role exists. What did I do wrong or how to set `x-ms-documentdb-query-enablecrosspartition` to `true` for `RoleManager` requests?

Comment: Have you referred to https://github.com/codekoenig/AspNetCore.Identity.DocumentDb/issues/9?

Comment: @JimXu those solutions didn't work for me. `For users and roles, add an additional, not auto-partitioned collection to your DocumentDb` done. `Fork this project and add the required code to support partitioning for your specific scenario` fork project for few methods? But even if I do this, how can I pass the partition key on role manager queries?

Comment: You can add `new FeedOptions { EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true }` to the line: https://github.com/codekoenig/AspNetCore.Identity.DocumentDb/blob/883db55ccaa2251c3870ce9bb2c9ea731fe57422/src/AspNetCore.Identity.DocumentDb/Stores/DocumentDbRoleStore.cs#L272.

Comment: @JimXu thanks. This should help.

Comment: Do you have any update?

Comment: @JimXu not yet. So far I switched to another project. I will try to change the source code and connect the "updated" repository to my project. I will write the result.

Comment: Is it OK for you?

Comment: @JimXu what exactly?

Comment: Sorry. I cannot understand it. Could you please describe it in detail?